# Magento 2.1.5 - Rest api media upload image not saving - Could not save the product

Tags: magento2, media

Working on Magento version - 2.1.5.

Hello Techies

I am working on magento 2 project and learning rest api .

I am trying to upload product image via rest api .

Url of rest api = http://127.0.0.1/megento2/index.php/rest/V1/products/{sku}/media.

Method i used **POST** as mention in magento 2 dev docs.

Below are the parameters :

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "media_type": "test",
    "label": "test",
    "position": 0,
    "disabled": true,
    "types": [
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "file": "test.png",
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "Here i have passed base64_encoded data of image",
      "type": "file/png",
      "name": "test.png"
    },
    }
  }
]
```

Not sure why but getting 400 Error and error message is like below :

> Product could not be saved

Your help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of Price field of the product.

Follow the **below steps :**

- Logged in with your magento 2 admin
- Edit the same product for which trying to upload image by rest api
- Check price is added or not ?  Price field is blank and thats why you
  have face this issue .
- Add Price for that product and Save the product
- Clear the cahe and your issue get resolved.

For more details refer this link - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5728

Comment: Strange but its working !!   I have added price and now image gets solved !! Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah Face the same issue previously !! Glad to help !! Keep helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look at my json template for this and we differ on a few things. I have:

- "media_type": "image"
- "types": ["image',"small_image","thumbnail"]
- "disabled": false

Also (and I think this is key) you need to post (with possible corrections from above):

```
{
  "entry":{
    "id": 0,
    "media_type": "test",
    "label": "test",
    "position": 0,
    "disabled": true,
    "types": [
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "file": "test.png",
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "Here i have passed base64_encoded data of image",
      "type": "file/png",
      "name": "test.png"
    },
    }
  }
}
```

Note the "entry". Why this is different to other calls I don't know.

Comment: Still getting the same error